# matplotlib pyplot not showing axes ticks or labels

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

When I run the following code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

In Jupyter notebook lab, I get back an image which only has a diagonal line and is otherwise blank. There are no axis ticks or labels, etc. This is in contrast to [the tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) which runs the same code and displays an image with axes. Any idea what might be wrong with my setup?

I checked the matplotlib version and it's 2.2.3.

I am running python 2.7.11, and IPython 5.8.0.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out the issue was caused by my Jupyter notebook being set to a dark background. The solution is to add this line of code:

```
plt.style.use('dark_background')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the theme of a Jupyter notebook is set to dark mode, this issue happens usually. the fix for this problem is to define the style by: `plt.style.use(style_name)`.

Where style_name can either be "fivethirtyeight", "classic", "dark_background", or "seaborn-white", etc. An extensive list of available themes is seen with the code `sorted(plt.style.available)`.